# Finding current location in android using google play services

Tags: java, android

I found a tutorial on the android developer site for finding the location using google play services.
The link:http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

It works perfectly fine.But there is a certain part of the code which is required for checking whether google play services is available on the device.But i dont know how to use it in my code.For example there is a method as follows:

```
private boolean servicesConnected() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                        isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates",
                    "Google Play services is available.");
            // Continue
            return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason.
        // resultCode holds the error code.
        } else {
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    resultCode,
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment =
                        new ErrorDialogFragment();
                // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        "Location Updates");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also there are other methods which i dont understand.Like the following:

```
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;
        // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }
        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }
        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
     * by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {

            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                    /*
                     * Try the request again
                     */

                    break;
                }

        }
     }
```

The first error dialog class if for displaying error.The onactivityresult is probably used when

```
connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,ONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
```

is called.

My question is where `servicesConnected()` should be called?

FULL CODE:

```
package com.example.locationdocseg;



import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
     // Global constants
    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private final static int
            CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    LocationClient mLocationClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    double current_latitude,current_longitude;
    // Milliseconds per second
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    // Update frequency in seconds
    public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
    // Update frequency in milliseconds
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL =
            MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
    // The fastest update frequency, in seconds
    private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
    // A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL =
            MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

    // Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested,isplayservice=false;
    // Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;
        // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }
        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }
        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
     * by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {

            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                    /*
                     * Try the request again
                     */

                    break;
                }

        }
     }

    private boolean servicesConnected() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                        isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates",
                    "Google Play services is available.");
            // Continue
            return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason.
        // resultCode holds the error code.
        } else {
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    resultCode,
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment =
                        new ErrorDialogFragment();
                // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        "Location Updates");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Open the shared preferences


//          isplayservice=true;
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(
                LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Get a SharedPreferences editor
        mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        /*
         * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
         * handle callbacks.
         */

        // Start with updates turned off
        mUpdatesRequested = false;

          mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
//        mLocationClient.connect();
          try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


          googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                    // Getting the position from the marker
                    LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

                    // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
                    TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

                    // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
                    TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

                    // Setting the latitude
                    tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + 8.505439);

                    // Setting the longitude
                    tvLng.setText("Longitude:"+ 76.971293);

                    // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                    return v;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                    return null;
                }
            });

    }
     @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // Save the current setting for updates
            mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", mUpdatesRequested);
            mEditor.commit();
            super.onPause();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {


        /*
         * Get any previous setting for location updates
         * Gets "false" if an error occurs
         */
        if (mPrefs.contains("KEY_UPDATES_ON")) {
            mUpdatesRequested =
                    mPrefs.getBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);

        // Otherwise, turn off location updates
        } else {
            mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);
            mEditor.commit();
        }
        super.onResume();

    }

     protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Connect the client.
            //mLocationClient.connect();
        }

        /*
         * Called when the Activity is no longer visible.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
             // If the client is connected

            if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
                /*
                 * Remove location updates for a listener.
                 * The current Activity is the listener, so
                 * the argument is "this".
                 */
//              removeLocationUpdates(MainActivity.this);
               mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            }
            /*
             * After disconnect() is called, the client is
             * considered "dead".
             */

            // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
            mLocationClient.disconnect();
            super.onStop();

        }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            showDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // Display the connection status

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mUpdatesRequested) {
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        }

        mCurrentLocation=mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

          current_latitude=mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
          current_longitude=mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
          placemarkersonmap();
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),current_latitude+" "+current_longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
//        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
//                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
//                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
//        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        current_latitude=location.getLatitude();
        current_longitude=location.getLongitude();


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if(googleMap!=null)
        {
            mLocationClient.connect();
            //placemarkersonmap();
        }
    }
    public void placemarkersonmap()
    {

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),current_latitude+" "+current_longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(8.505439, 76.971293));


     googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all from your `onCreate()` method just call this method. After calling this method, and where exactly you get callback of this method, check it, is it available or not. If its available then proceed to fetch location data else show error dialog that Google Play Services is not available in your device, please enable from settings.

Comment: should i do like if(servicesConnected(){ //rest of code in oncreate//}

Comment: when i tried the above way I got NPE in onresume and onpause methods.